# Devise/Ruby on Rails: NoMethodError in Devise/sessionsController#create when trying to login existing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a RoR application with Devise for user authentication. Devise is used for local user registration / authentication. Latest Devise is suppose to be also :omniauthable - supporting Facebook and other logins. So I tried doing it as described in the instruction: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Facebook authentication actually started to work. The problem is now that when local user tries to login now, I get this error:

NoMethodError in Devise/sessionsController#create
undefined method `redirect_location' for #

So, Facebook login works, and local login doesn't. Any hint what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a mixup with gemsets and using different stuff from different versions of the Devise.

Comment: Can you be any more specific? Which gemsite was right, which version of devise was right?